# Minimum distance between a function and a set in $L^2[-\pi ,\pi ]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the function $f(x)=(x+1)^2$. How do I find the distance between $f$ and $\mathrm {span}\{\cos (nx)\}_{n\ge 0}$ in $L^2[-\pi ,\pi ]$?

I tried to calculate  $\inf ||f-g||$ for any $g\in \mathrm {span}\{\cos (nx)\}$, or to find any such $g$ that satisfies $\langle f-g,\cos(nx)\rangle=0$ for any $n$, but it is all too complicated and I think I am missing something trivial. Any ideas?

Comment: Project $f$ onto $\text{span}\{\cos(nx)\}_{n\geq0}$, subtract this projection from $f$, and take the norm.  That's the distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g$ be the $2\pi$ periodic function defined on $[-\pi,\pi]$ by
$g(x)=\frac12\left(f(x)+f(-x)\right)$.

Now, $g$ is even so it has a cosine convergent fourier series expansion in $L^2$. Moreover, since $h=f-g$ is an odd function, then clearly, $ h\bot V$, where $V=\overline{{\rm span}\{\cos (nx):n\ge0\}}$. So, $g$ is the orthogonal projection of $f$ on $V$. Hence
$$\eqalign{d^2(f,V)&=\Vert h\Vert^2=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi|f(x)-f(-x)|^2dx\cr
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^\pi\left((1+x)^2-(1-x)^2\right)^2dx\cr
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^\pi\left(4x\right)^2dx=\frac{8\pi^2}{3}
}$$
So, $d(f,V)=2\pi\sqrt{\frac23}$.

Comment: On the same matter. In the answer you used the fact that a function on $L^2[-a ,a ]$ can be written as a unique sum of an even and an odd function. But what if the space is $L^2[0,1]$? Are there any other ways to decompose a function uniquely? For example, the distance between the fuction $x$ on $L^2[0,1]$ and the space $\mathrm {span} \{x^{2n}\}_{n\in \mathbf N}$. If it was in $L^2[-a,a]$ then I could follow your last answer, but this is not the case.

Comment: @MasterJ, ln the general case you have to calculate the orthogonal projection on your subspace. But, this might be the subject of another question maybe.